# Problems while zipping two lists as a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I have the following lists:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C']

b = ['2', '3', 2, 3]
```

I am zipping them as follows in order to get a dict:

```
a_dict = dict(zip(a,b))
```

However, since the final object is a dict I cant have repeated keys:

```
{'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': 3}
```

Which alternatives can I have in order to have something like this? (*):

```
{'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C':2, 'C': 3}
```

I tried to convert everything as tuples, however I am using a pop to replace some keys and values from the dictionary:

```
data['A'] = data.pop('B')
```

Therefore, I cant use a tuple format. Therefore, given the above two lists, how can I get (*)?

Comment: You may need a different data structure since a dict cannot have duplicate keys. It sounds like you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's your ultimate goal here?

Comment: What do expect `result['C']` to be in your proposed object?

Comment: you cant get `{'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C':2, 'C': 3}` one key will point to one value in a dict you can get something like `{'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C':[2, 3]}`

Comment: My expected goal is to get something similar to (*), it was clearly stated @PM2Ring

Comment: Dictionaries are not able to contain duplicate keys, so then what tou want?

Comment: You did not answer what I asked. If you have `result = what you want`, and you try to retrieve `'C'`, similar to `result['C']` in a usual dict, what do expect to get?

Comment: What should be the effect of `data['C'] = data.pop('B')` and `data['A'] = data.pop['C']`?

Comment: No, (*) is your immediate goal, which you think you need to solve Y. But what's the real X problem that you're trying to solve? A dict with duplicate keys is impossible, so you will need something else, but to give you good advice about that we need to know about the actual task you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way to resolve key conflicts while still maintaining most of the benefit of the quick indexing of a dict is to turn the values into lists:

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(a, b):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

so that `d` becomes:

```
{'A': ['2'], 'B': ['3'], 'C': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is not achievable by using dicts. You could either resolve the name conflict by using @blhsing's answer, or use sets to get somewhat close to your desired result as I suspect that you want to check for already existing combinations in a data structure because you tried using tuples.

```
c = set(zip(a, b))
```

so `c` becomes:

```
{('B', '3'), ('C', 3), ('A', '2'), ('C', 2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `defaultdict` of `collections`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(a,b):
   d[k].append(v)
```

And now:

```
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['2'], 'B': ['3'], 'C': [2, 3]}
```

If care about single element lists:

```
print({k:(v if len(v)-1 else v[0]) for k,v in d.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'A': '2', 'B': '3', 'C': [2, 3]}
```